# Is there a shorthand declaration in Swift for an empty Set similar to Array

Tags: arrays, swift, set

In short, with Swift I can declare an empty Array of a particular type with something akin to the following (without having to use the initializer syntax):

`var myArray : [Int] = []`

I have not been able to find a similar shorthand to declare an empty Set since they both use the brackets.  I either have to use the initializer syntax or I have to use:

`var mySet : Set<Int> = []`

Which, granted, is not odious, but I wondered if I am missing some syntax sugar somewhere.

(added) "Shorthand" was a bad choice of words.  What I was really after was clarity, I guess.  In the example for myArray, it's pretty clear what is going on, and it matches the format for a lot of other common variable declarations.  The angle <> notation is a bit more obscure.

Comment: I don't see how you could make it any more succinct than just `[]`, really.

Comment: I would just do `Set<Int>()`.

Comment: Isn't using the initialiser syntax shorter? `var mySet = Set<Int>()`

Comment: `var set: Set<Int> = .init()`

Comment: @LeoDabus Seems like the worst of both worlds

Comment: I am just showing what options he has.

Comment: @LeoDabus Fair enough!

Comment: Btw Swift is a type inferred language. if you are assign some elements to your set you can simply say `var set: Set = [1,2,3]`

Comment: "The angle <> notation is a bit more obscure" No, it isn't. — This has devolved into total opinion. It doesn't matter what one likes; the question is, what there is. And the answer is, there is no implicit Set literal like there's an Array literal, so the word `Set` absolutely must appear somewhere or you won't get a set. One must just live with the options that there are. File an enhancement request with Apple if it really bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact no such syntax in the current (5.x) version of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by *without having to use the initializer syntax*

`var mySet = Set<Int>()` is my preferred shorthand

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var set1 = Set<Int>() 

set1 = [10,20,30]

print("set \(set1)") // [10,20,30]

set1 = []

print("set \(set1)") // []
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).